# Asynchronous onHashChange fires when hash has not changed

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am seeing [onHashChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) fire in Firefox 3.6.13 when the hash has not changed. In the following scenario, I change the hash and then immediately afterwards register a custom hash change callback. I do not change the hash after registering the callback, but nontheless, my callback is fired.

1. `window.location += '#newHash'`
   causes the address bar to update
   immediately.
2. Firefox notes the hash
   change and gets ready to fire an
   asynchronous onHashChange callback,
   which is an empty function at this
   point.
3. I register my own custom hash
   change callback:
   `window.onhashchange = function() {
   console.info('custom hash
   callback'); };`
4. Finally the browser
   yields control to do asynchronous
   events. It fires the onHashChange
   callback it scheduled in step 2.

This is a simplified example of my real code. My real callback actually updates the database through AJAX, so this unexpected hash change triggering puts unnecessary burden on the server and is just logically incorrect.

Can someone verfiy that the above scenario is indeed happening, rather than some other coding error? It's confusing that the [bug filed against Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=515190) to make onHashChange synchronous has been marked resolved/fixed. I don't know if FF 3.6.13 already has the synchronous fix or what future version of FF will have this change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the comments on the bug you linked to, you'll see that the behaviour was reverted back to being asynchronous.

One way to get the behaviour that you want would be to wrap the change to `window.onhashchange` in a `window.setTimeout` function, with a timeout of 0, for example:

```
window.location += '#newHash';
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.onhashchange = function() { console.info('custom hash callback'); }
}, 0);
```