# Disregard onHashChange during manual editing of window.location

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a way to NOT run [onHashChange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) when I manually edit the hash with javascript?

```
window.location = 'http://www.site.com/foo.html#newHash';
```

I'd like to only run onHashChange when the user hits *back* or *forward* on the browser or types in a new hash herself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the cleanest approach, but you could set a flag before changing the hash via JS. I've wrapped this in a function - `windowLocation()`.

```
function windowLocation(url) {
    window.jsHashFlag = true;
    window.newURL = url;
    window.location = url;
}

function hashChange(e) {
    if(window.jsHashFlag && e.newURL == window.newURL) {
        // hash changed programmatically
        window.jsHashFlag = false;
        window.newURL = '';
    }
    else {
        // hash changed manually
        // do something
    }
}
window.jsHashFlag = false;
window.onhashchange = hashChange;

// ...

windowLocation('http://www.site.com/foo.html#newHash');
```

Comment: This is a very very ingenious solution. However, I'd have to do more testing to make sure this works 100% of the time. OnHashChange is actually asynchronous, so your flag can sometimes be wrong during some split seconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979971/asynchronous-onhashchange-fires-when-hash-has-not-changed

Comment: Modified the code a bit. Added a check to see if `e.newURL == window.newURL` as well as checking the flag. `window.newURL` gets set when there's a programmatic change to the hash in my `windowLocation()` function. Since JS is single-threaded this should be enough to guarantee that when the hashChange event is triggered you know for sure what triggered it.

Comment: Do you think I should just re-write my History class to take on this behavior? Currently, my hash changes cause the web application to go the the next / previous step. I believe this is not good coding practice to have the side effect of the hash change actually move the application forward. Wouldn't it be cleaner code to go the other way around? Move the application forward with traditional code AND THEN write the hash manually as a history marker?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve based on this comment. I'd recommend you open a new question so that you can include additional detail / code.

Comment: I thought one of the rules was "no open ended answers". Let me explain: I've attached a hash change listener that will move the web application forward or back depending on what the hash was changed to, say #finished, #saving, etc... If someone were to read my code for the first time, wouldn't they find it strange that the order of operations is 1) changing the hash, 2) the application moves forward as a side effect? My proposal to fix this poor coding is to revamp my History class with your solution. Whenever I change the hash with JS, it will solely be for used for history marking.

Comment: I think this would be fine as a new question, and the extra space available might help to clarify what you're doing. But, assuming I understand you correctly, I suppose it comes down to the behavior you're trying to implement. Do you want the back button to navigate through hashes that you've set programmatically or just hashes that the user manually triggered? If the former, then every hash should be included in the history and your current order of operations seems ok. If the latter then there's really no need to even store the hashes as part of a history, and they can be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to hook into the onHashChange event with jquery bbq (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) and conditionally trigger whichever actions you'd like. I'm not sure how to detect back/forward clicks though.